# Sacar datos de Json

Tags: php, jquery, json, api

Llevo rato intentando sacar los datos del `JSON` de la `API` de League of Legends y no encuentro manera. Pongo el ejemplo de uno de los `JSON` que me es imposible de recorrer.

```
{
    "23385178": {
        "summonerId": 23385178,
        "pages": [
            {
                "id": 34451272,
                "name": "Thresh",
                "current": false,
                "masteries": [
                    {
                        "id": 6342,
                        "rank": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6241,
                        "rank": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6311,
                        "rank": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6221,
                        "rank": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6211,
                        "rank": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6322,
                        "rank": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6332,
                        "rank": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6232,
                        "rank": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6362,
                        "rank": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6352,
                        "rank": 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 34451273,
                "name": "Alistar",
                "current": false,
                "masteries": [
                    {
                        "id": 6342,
                        "rank": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6311,
                        "rank": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6241,
                        "rank": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6221,
                        "rank": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6211,
                        "rank": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6322,
                        "rank": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6332,
                        "rank": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6231,
                        "rank": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6352,
                        "rank": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6362,
                        "rank": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

El `JSON` lo estoy tratando como leí en otro post de aquí.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://euw.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/EUW/v1.4/summoner/23385178/masteries?api_key=RGAPI-de016c14-78f2-4e19-82a7-33526d8bed4c",
        dataType: "json",
    }).then(function(data) {
        $('.parrId').append();
        $('.parrName').append();
        $('.parrIcon').append();
        $('.parrLvl').append();
    });
});
```

Mi intención es colocar en los distintos párrafos (parrId, parrName, etc) la información extraída del `JSON`. Obviamente habría que recorrerlo para extraer toda la información, pero soy incapaz hasta de extraer el primer elemento, creo que me esta molestando el nombre del `array`.

Comment: El indice en este caso `23385178` será fijo , puedes iniciar por ahí `data['23385178']['pages']` luego con un for simple se puede recorrer lo devuelto , el campo `masteries` donde lo quieres añadir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El objeto de la respuesta tiene una clave fija, la cual es: **23385178**, por lo tanto para poder recorrer el objeto y mostrar la información deseada deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://euw.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/EUW/v1.4/summoner/23385178/masteries?api_key=RGAPI-de016c14-78f2-4e19-82a7-33526d8bed4c",
    dataType: "json",
  }).then(function(data) {
    // Definimos nuestro arreglo pages respecto a la clave fija
    var pages = data['23385178'].pages;
    // Recorremos nuestro arreglo pages
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
      // Creamos un objeto para cada pocisión
      var obj = pages[i];
      // Ponemos nuestro resultado
      $('#result').append('<b>Id: </b>' + obj.id + ' <b>Name: </b>' + obj.name + '<br />');
      // Realizamos otro ciclo anidado recorriendo
      // el arreglo masteries dentro de nuestro objeto actual
      for (var j = 0; j < obj.masteries.length; j++) {
        // Ponemos nuestro resultado
        $('#result').append('<b>Id: </b>' + obj.masteries[j].id + ' <b>Rank: </b>' + obj.masteries[j].rank + '<br />');
      }
      $('#result').append('<hr />')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#result {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: En lugar del "data['23385178'].pages" tomar el dato (que pienso puede ser dinámico, solo que aqui lo puso fijo el usuario -solcitante del apoyo-) de la "url" ya que el "23385178" se está enviando (desde luego sería variable con ese valor); así servirá para cualquier caso.

Comment: Obviamente, no es que sea difícil implementar eso de forma dinámica, solo respondí con respecto al ejemplo que puso el autor

Comment: @Jorius me ganaste segundos en publicar ;) . es una respuesta correcta y simple. +1

Comment: Muchas Gracias a todos, efectivamente la solución funciona y la entiendo perfectamente.